# Como hacer que cada padre tenga la altura de su respectivo hijo

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass, pug

tengo el consiguiente código pug:

```
section.text-overlap-img
article
    .container
        .row.justify-content-around
            .col-md-5
                .wrapper-img.bg-line-white.adjust-height
                    img(src="img/johan-cruyff.png")
            .col-md-5
article
    .container
        .row.justify-content-around
            .col-md-5
                .wrapper-img.bg-line-white.adjust-height
                    img(src="img/ejemplo.png")
            .col-md-5
```

Quisiera saber , como hacer que cada .wrapper-img coja la altura de su respectivo hijo en jquery, ahora lo que tengo es:

```
$(".text-overlap-img .wrapper-img").each(function(){

var imgHeight = $(".wrapper-img img").height();

$(".wrapper-img img").css({'height' : imgHeight });});
```

Y no me funciona para nada, me coge como altura la del primer elemento, y me la aplica la misma a todos los demás.
Si me pudieráis ayudar os estaría super agradecido.
Por cierto no me coje de forma automática la altura porque el img, esta con un position absolue, cosas de la maquetación...

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? Hice una pequeña modificación en mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque estás tomando erróneamente el alto. Según esto: `var imgHeight = $(".wrapper-img img").height();`, imgHeight va a ser siempre de la altura del primero. Eso es debido a que vuelves a seleccionar todos los elementos con esa clase y siempre devuelve la misma lista. Lo correcto sería esto

```
$(".text-overlap-img .wrapper-img").each(function(){

var imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height();

$(this).css({'height' : imgHeight });
});
```

Comment: Tampoco me lo coje, he probado y no me funciona, no me coge ningun alto, me lo deja con alto 0

Comment: Prueba de nuevo con el código que le he quitado algo

Comment: Me coge la altura del ultimo, y me la aplica al primero, ahora el último me lo coje guay pero el primero coje la altura del último

Comment: Ahora sí jaja. Mil perdones, estoy trabajando mientras hago esto